bottomNavigationBar opacity not working as expected
Within a Scaffold widget, am creating a BottomNavigationBar, as follows:
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.1),
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    ...

When the opacity is a high value, the background is red. When the opacity is a low value as above, I expect the color of the bar to be a very light red. However, it is a murky grey. It is as if the underlying color upon which the bar is being painted is grey, however I do not know where this is coming from.
In main.dart, am doing the following to try to set the underlying background to white:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData().copyWith(
         canvasColor: Colors.white,
         scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,

This does not appear to make a difference.
I have also tried wrapping the BottomNanigationBar in a ThemeData widget, as follows:
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.white),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(

However, this does not make a difference.
Could anyone assist, thanks

Please share the image you want to generate.

Do not have an image to share - want red with a low opacity, so the (should be white underlying color) shows through, and the result in a very light shade of red

With your given code result is : https://i.imgur.com/02f99xD.png,
what changes you required?

Thanks for your image, which looks like red with grey underneath. If you reduce the opacity it will be more grey. I want white underneath the red, not grey.

I have added code, hope it helps.

Try below code with elevation: 0 to BottomNavigationBar
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Colors.white,
                Colors.red,
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.book), label: "Book"),
            ],
          ),
        )


Thank you very much - this is close enough to what I want that I have been able to adapt it. Much appreciated !
